# Entity Framework, Multiple values 1 cell/ Datagridview c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a datagridview and I need to somehow have 2 values in my database in the same cell.

I need to have 2 checkboxes in the same column which are currently smallints in the database.

I am using entity framework if that helps?

Also I need to be able to store these values back to the database!

I'm not entirely sure where to start so any pointers would be brilliant!

Code is a basic EF with a DataBindingProjection class,

```
    private void HtReports_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

        fmsEntities context = new fmsEntities();
        var query = (from f in context.funerals
                    where f.IsPencil == 0
                    join d in context.deceaseddetails on f.DeceasedID equals d.ID
                    join i in context.funeralservices on f.ID equals i.FuneralID
                    where i.IsAlternative == 0
                    join h in context.htvalues on f.HtValuesID equals h.ID
                    join p in context.placeofdeaths on f.PlaceOfDeathID equals p.ID
                    join c in context.coroners on f.CoronerID equals c.ID
                     let val1 = d.DateOfDeath
                     let val2 = d.DateOfBirth
                     let val3 = i.Date
                     orderby i.Date
                     select new
                     {
                         d.LastName,
                         d.FirstName,
                         val2,
                         val1,
                         f.CremOrInt,
                         FormsSigned1 = h.FormsSigned1 ?? 0,
                         FormsSigned2 = h.FormsSigned2 ?? 0,
                     }).ToList();

        var dataobjects = query.Select(d => new DataBindingProjection
        {
            DeceasedName = (d.FirstName + Environment.NewLine + d.LastName),
            DOBDOD = (d.val2.HasValue ? d.val2.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty) + Environment.NewLine +
            (d.val1.HasValue ? d.val1.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty),
            CremInt = d.CremOrInt
        }).ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataobjects;

        dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Last Name" + Environment.NewLine + "First Name";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "DOB" + Environment.NewLine + "DOD";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Crem/Int";
    }


    private class DataBindingProjection
    {
        public string DeceasedName {get; set;}
        public string DOBDOD {get; set;}
        public string CremInt { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this winforms or wpf, or asp.net?

I would start be creating a custom control that takes these two values, and displays your checkboxes.  Then feeding the data into said control and putting that into your datagrid.

I'm not sure if this is similar to your usecase but you might want to check this out, explaning how to get mulitple controls in a single datagridview cell.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/c28399bb-9d50-4a1e-b671-3dbaebb5cc69/multiple-controls-in-a-single-datagridview-cell

This may not answer your question completely but might give you a head start

Comment: Thanks I haven't tried using custom controls at all so might help with having 2 checkboxes in the same cell!